# Calculation of 4 digit numbers

Tags: c, calculation

What I am trying to do in the code below is to to make the input a four-digit number (if it's not already) and then sort the digits in the number in an ascending and descending order. `x` is ascending, `y` is descending. Then I want to subtract `x` and `y` until I get the result `6174` of the subtraction.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number, count = 0, digit, pow = 0, result = 1, counter, temp,
        x = 0, y = 0, i, j, substract = 0, count1 = 0;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    while (substract != 6174 && substract >= 0) {
        substract = 0;
        if (count1 > 0) {
            temp = substract;
        } else {
            temp = number;
        }
        while (temp > 0) {
            digit = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            count++;
        }
        if (count < 4) {
            pow = 4 - count;
            /* Calculate base^exponent */
            for (counter = 0; counter < pow; counter++) {
                result = result * 10;
            }
            number = number * result;
        }

        for (i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0 && j <= 9; i--, j++) {
            int tmpNumber = number;
            while (tmpNumber > 0) {
                int digit = tmpNumber % 10;
                if (digit == i) {
                    x *= 10;
                    x += digit;
                } else
                if (digit == j) {
                    y *= 10;
                    y += digit;
                }
                tmpNumber /= 10;
            }
        }
        substract = x - y;
        count++;

        printf("\n x %d", x);
        printf("\n y %d", y);
        printf("\n substract %d", x - y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input `3542` What I expect as an output is this

**input:**

```
3524
```

**output:**

```
x 5432
y 2345
subtract 3087
x 8730
y 0378
subtract 8352
x 8532
y 2358
subtract 6174
```

But what I  get is actually this:

**input:**

```
3524
```

**output:**

```
x 5432
y 2345
subtract 3087

x 54325432
y 23452345
subtract 30873087
```

I think the problem is something with the `x` and `y`. I have to reset them to zero at some point. But I don't know where. I've tried every single place in the code. If anyone knows where I do wrong I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: I would recommend trying to give your variables more meaningful names.

Comment: Inheritance to the next loop is incorrect. `x`, `y`, `count` These must be reset.  Conversely, `substract` should not be reset to the beginning of the loop. `number`, `temp` and `count1` have confusion in use.  Rethink about these things.

Comment: Start with not defining all your variables on one line, but one line for each (and define variables in the block they are used)

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/dci4Gp) However, some problems remain.

Comment: [another approach](https://ideone.com/ipz516)

Comment: I've tried your solution @BLUEPIXY and it works.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The program fails for multiple reasons:

- You do not reset `x` and `y` to `0` for each iteration
- `result` should also be reset to `1`
- The initial phase of the loop is too complicated: you should test if `substract` is `0` or `6174` to stop the loop and store `substract` to `number` at the end of the loop.

Here is a simpler version that does not need to make number have 4 digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number;

    if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number >= 0 && number < 10000) {
        for (;;) {
            int x = 0, y = 0, substract;
            for (int i = 9, j = 0; i >= 0 && j <= 9; i--, j++) {
                for (int tmp = number, n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
                    int digit = tmp % 10;
                    if (digit == i) {
                        x *= 10;
                        x += digit;
                    } else
                    if (digit == j) {
                        y *= 10;
                        y += digit;
                    }
                    tmp /= 10;
                }
            }
            substract = x - y;
            printf("x %d\n", x);
            printf("y %d\n", y);
            printf("substract %d\n", substract);
            if (substract == 0 || substract == 6174)
                break;
            number = substract;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```